# Make fontspec use TEXMF instead of Windows-Fonts folder

Tags: fontspec

I am currently investigating the options of using a corporate font available in OTF for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX through `fontspec`. Everything works so far, but one of the fonts is available in the Windows fonts folder, as well as the TEXMF tree. `fontspec` seems to prefer the Windows fonts folder in this case and I would like to know if there is a way how I can tell fontspec to prefer the TEXMF tree over the fonts folder.

This is how I load the font with fontspec:

```
\setmainfont{CorporateFont}[
  Extension= .otf ,
  UprightFont= *-Regular ,
  BoldFont= *-Bold ,
  ItalicFont= *-RegularItalic ,
  BoldItalicFont= *-BoldItalic]
```

The files `CorporateFont-Regular.otf`, `CorporateFont-Bold.otf`, `CorporateFont-RegularItalic.otf`, and `CorporateFont-BoldItalic.otf` are residing in both of the following folders:

`.../mytexmftree/fonts/opentype/Corporate/Font/CorporateFont-Regular.otf`

`C:/WINDOWS/Fonts/CorporateFont-Regular.otf`

Of course I know that I could set the `Path`, but we want to roll out the font for MiKTeX on Windows and TeXlive on Linux, so is it possible to tell `fontspec` to use TEXMF in general and not a fixed location or relative to the file in compilation?

Comment: that is not really a fontspec problem, it simply asks the engines to find the fonts. With xelatex you will have to change the font config settings (how depends on the OS and the tex system), with lualatex you can use a luaotfload.conf file (here fontspec could also use the kpse lookup, but imho it is not implemented yet).

Comment: OK, then I will have a look into the XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX font loading mechanisms, I thought this is the job of `fontspec`.

Comment: IIRC on XeTeX, your document should already use the texmf version (Normally XeTeX uses a texmf font iff the font is specified by filename instead of fontname)

Comment: @MarcelKrüger do you know how I can confirm this? In LuaLaTeX I can see the used fonts at the end of the log, how is it in XeTeX?

Comment: @TobiBS `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1`, then look into your log file (Attention, it will not be at the end of the log, so you might have to search a bit)

Comment: @MarcelKrüger, great that helps for debugging! However it confirmed, that XeLaTeX also uses the fonts from Windows, at least he version I have to use for the moment: `XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (MiKTeX 2.9.6400 64-bit)`